# Should I pass by reference when using the erase-remove idiom in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Should I pass by reference when using the erase-remove idiom in c++?

For example:

```
void Country::clean()
{
cities.erase( std::remove_if(
  cities.begin(),
  cities.end(),
  [](City city) -> bool { return city.getNumberOfBuildings() == 0; }
),
  cities.end()
  );
}
```

Maybe it would be better to change the lambda function line to:

```
[](City &city) -> bool { return city.getNumberOfBuildings() == 0; }
```

and pass city by reference?

Thanks

Comment: Why not constant reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no benefit from making a copy, so you should probably pass a reference. But what you should do is use a `const` reference:

```
[](const City &city) -> bool { return city.getNumberOfBuildings() == 0; }
```

Note that in this case you do not have to specify the return type.

Comment: And he can change the comparison to 0 to `!condition`